# Why this line of code forces me to clean every time I build it?

Tags: android, coding-style, transition

Hello,

I am still fairly new to coding for Android but this is puzzling me a bit.

I have written a few apps and prior to this I could build fairly regularly without doing a clean first. Prior to final release I would always do that of course but during development only if something happened I did not expect.

Everything was going normally and I came across some code to affect transitions so the screen would fade into one another and it works nicely however when I add one single line the line that does the the function the app needs to be clean before it is run for a development device.

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
```

If I add this line and I do not clean it cause a failure on this line but if I clean first then the build succeeds and everything works just fine.

Here is the fade-in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />
```

Here is the fade-out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="0.0" />
```

I generally place this line near the `onCreate()`:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String status;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.introalev);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);

    // ...
}
```

Any ideas on how I could fix this so I do not have to clean E V E R Y time?

Comment: Not the solution you want to hear, but I'd advise just switching to IntelliJ IDEA instead of Eclipse. I'd run into this sort of thing all the time with Eclipse.

Comment: I work on the MAC platform I have not heard of intelliJ IDEA is it for MAC I on occasion needs to code for iphone as well so I have to stay on MAC is it to get up and running and start to developing any negatives to it. Can it do signed application as well or do I have to do something else for that. I am asking because I am getting a new MAC and if it is a great deal more reliable then I will look into it as well what about SDK support and simulators sorry about all the questions

Comment: Great thing about Jetbrains (the company who do Intellij IDEA) is that they also do AppCode for iOS.  More or less the same IDE for both platforms and AppCode is in my opinion significantly better than xCode, especially in debugging and refactoring - 2 areas xCode really sucks in.

Comment: "If I add this line and I do not clean it cause a failure on this line" - what error happens?

Comment: GREAAATTTTT Now two more things I have to figure out but I do thank for the information

Comment: @JeffJanes Yeah, I use IDEA on both OS X and Windows 7. In my opinion it's far more stable and reliable. It's not too difficulty to move things between either, as IDEA can import Eclipse project structures. I don't know of anything Eclipse can do that IDEA *cannot* do; I use it for my signed, published application.

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/ You just need the Community Edition (free).

Answer (score 0):

I actually found an answer though it probably will not count as the correct answer by coders but it solves the main issue I was asking about which was to not have it happen. I t probably has to with the API level it said something about requiring 5 and my minimum was 4 so I am not sure

BUT while there I saw a quick edit to not search for this issue in this project which 
I  selected.....

that's offending someone I know.

In my defense it seems like it is only checking for something not finding it and giving an error but the code runs fine once I do a clean so if it was a critical error it should stop it again but this does not happen so I am thinking something like a warning error. So my problem is resolved though maybe not in the best way.